# Zend router with regex

Tags: php, regex, zend-framework, zend-route

I'm trying to route all segment but also have exceptions.
So I want to route :any except (home|about|contact). Something like that.

I've manage to do this in codeigniter but I'm having a little more difficulties in Zend Framework. In codeigniter I would write this line in my configs/routes.php file:

`$route['^(?!home|about|contact)\S*'] = "category";`

This is what I have in my routes.xml for my zend project.

```
    <category>

            <type>Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Regex</type>

        <route>(?!home|about|contact)</route>

        <defaults>

            <controller>category</controller>

            <action>index</action>

        </defaults>

        <reverse>%s</reverse>

    </category>
```

Comment: What happens if you try something really simple?  Does plain `home` successfully match "home"?  Then try `home|about`, and gradually build up your regex to identify the problem.

Comment: I solved my problem. In my definition of the route I needed to include the entire regex that I used in codeigniter ^(?!home|about|contact)\S*. So I would have <route>(^(?!home|about|contact)\S*)</route> and all the url's not containing home or about or contact will go to my category controller. thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the answer based on zfded's comment,

```
<route>(^(?!home|about|contact)\S*)</route>
```

should be the correct route.